# How do I pull in data from another table across many fields, without inefficiently creating several separate tables?

Tags: powerbi

I am kind of a Power BI beginner, so please be patient with me.

I have one table "[games](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvATk.png)" and another table "[champion_info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI1WK.png)"

The "games" table contains a unique ID for each row, "gameID", but non-unique IDs, "t1_champ[1-5]id", which are references to the actual champion names found in the "champion_info" table.

I'm wondering what might be the best way to set things up so that I could effectively reference the champion name in visualizations rather than their numerical "champid". From what I gathered, I could set up 30 separate tables, so that each one could contain an active relationship, but that seems cumbersome as there would need to be 30 separate tables setup to account for all the references to this ID.

Can you think of a better way to handle this situation? or is this the most efficient solution? Your guidance is very much appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: Look up how to unpivot your `games` table to turn all your champion ID columns into one column. This will allow you do establish a single one-to-many relationship between `games` and `champion info`. But ultimately this depends on what other information is in `games` and what you want to calculate.

Comment: For more info on Unpivot columns: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/unpivot-column